# не могу подключить spring ORM

Tags: java, spring

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу подключить spring orm. Кто знает подскажите в чём проблема  Вылетает исключение:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.test.model' while setting bean property 'packageToScan'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.test.model' available
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.test"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packageToScan" ref="org.test.model"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: не может найти бин org.test.model. у вас вообще такой класс существует и что это за класс?

Comment: <property name="packageToScan" ref="org.test.model"/> на сколько я понял я здесь задаю пакет, а spring сам там должен искать бины, Я правильно понял? Порывшись в интернетах нашел такой вариант:  <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>org.test.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property> так работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в опечатке `<property name="packageToScan" ref="org.test.model"/>`
правильно `<property name="packagesToScan" ref="org.test.model"/>`
Вот так я потратил день жизни на опечатку))